# eventual consistency and updates

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I want to be able to update only certain attributes of an existing item, without first getting the item.

First, am I right in assuming that this would work if the 'ignore null values' option is set for the operation? That is, only the specified attributes will get updated, and the rest will be unchanged.

Second, suppose that the update happens a very short period after the item is added to the table. Is it possible that the update will fail or that the original data will get lost, since the operation will be received by a server that doesn't have the item data yet? If so, does the 'consistent read' option have any effect on this type of operation?

Answer (score 0):

First, there is no different insert/update in dynamodb. Even the [UpdateAPI](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_UpdateItem.html) will create an object if it was not present when updating. IMO, if you use a mapper it's best to create different objects with different attributes for clarity even though ignore null is suppose to do what you want.

The data will not get lost, if the original call reached and executed in dynamodb then the second will work "after it" thus update.